# Javascript third quote

Tags: javascript, quote

```
addFontBox: function(a, b, d) {
    c(a).append("<div class="font-box"><span class="title-box">" + 
    r[b] + "</span><div class="select-wrapper"><select id="" + b + "" 
    class="form-control"></select></div></div>"), 
    c("#" + b).append("<option value="ubuntu">Ubuntu</option><option                 
    value="ubuntu-bold">Ubuntu Bold</option>"), 
    c("#" + b).append("<option value="roboto">Roboto</option><option 
    value="roboto-bold">Roboto Bold</option>"), 
    c("#" + b).append("<option value="oswald">Oswald</option><option 
    value="oswald-bold">Oswald Bold</option>"), 
    c("#" + b).val(x[b])
```

Here I'm getting `Line 2: Parse error. missing ) after argument list`

Line 2: Parse error. missing } after function body on JSNice, can I add quote or something after append (and before closing bracket)? I don't really want to interrupt any of the code inside it.

Comment: Reconsider your use of double quote: you shoud escape with \ the inner ones or change the outer ones with single quote characters: this is wrong `"<div class="font-box"><span class="title-box">"`, this is correct: `'<div class="font-box"><span class="title-box">'` this too: `"<div class=\"font-box\"><span class=\"title-box\">"`

Comment: replace the double quote by a single quote, like this: `c(a).append("<div class='font-box'>......`

Comment: you need to know the single quotes double quotes escape behaviour @Alvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this changes in your code will helps you

```
addFontBox: function(a, b, d) {
        c(a).append("<div class='font-box'><span class='title-box'>" + r[b] + "</span><div class='select-wrapper'><select id='" + b + "' class='form-control'></select></div></div>"),
                c("#" + b).append("<option value='ubuntu'>Ubuntu</option><option value='ubuntu-bold'>Ubuntu Bold</option>"),
                c("#" + b).append("<option value='roboto'>Roboto</option><option value='roboto-bold'>Roboto Bold</option>"), 
                c("#" + b).append("<option value='oswald'>Oswald</option><option value='oswald-bold'>Oswald Bold</option>"), 
                c("#" + b).val(x[b])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\"` to escape the quotes:

```js
addFontBox: function(a, b, d) {
            c(a).append("<div class=\"font-box\"><span class=\"title-box\">" + r[b] + "</span><div class=\"select-wrapper\"><select id=\" + b + \" class=\"form-control\"></select></div></div>\"), 
            c("#" + b).append("<option value=\"ubuntu\">Ubuntu</option><option value=\"ubuntu-bold\">Ubuntu Bold</option>"), 
            c("#" + b).append("<option value=\"roboto\">Roboto</option><option value=\"roboto-bold\">Roboto Bold</option>"), 
            c("#" + b).append("<option value=\"oswald\">Oswald</option><option value=\"oswald-bold\">Oswald Bold</option>"), c("#" + b).val(x[b])
```

or use ` as delimiter

```
`" as many quotes " as you " want `
```

Answer (score 0):

`use id=" + b + "`

instead of

```
id="" + b + ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got unescaped quotes in the string, so it thinks that the string is only

```
"<div class="
```

Then it sees font-box as an error.

You could either escape the quotes, i.e.

```
"<div class=\"font-box\"><span class=\"title-box\">" + ...
```

or use single quotes

```
'<div class="font-box"><span class="title-box">' + ...
```